# Momentum Operator for Schrödinger's equation notation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, momentum, complex-numbers

I'm studying Chemistry but we are studying Quantum Physics as a separate module and I had a question regarding the momentum operator.

In the lecture, we were given the following information:

> The momentum operator is as follows: 
>  
>   $$p_x = \frac{\hbar}{i} \frac{d}{dx} = -i\hbar \frac{d}{dx}$$
>   Hence we only differentiate the function only once to find the momentum but twice for the energy.

Now I'm a bit confused here.

I know that $i = \sqrt{-1}$ but how has the lecturer made the jump from
$$p_x = \frac{\hbar}{i} \frac{d}{dx}$$

to $$p_{x} = -i\hbar \frac{d}{dx}$$

without changing any terms?

I thought it would work if multiplying by $-i$ on both sides that

$$-i \times p_{x} = -i\hbar \frac{d}{dx}$$

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Really simple, you just need the facts that $i \cdot i = -1$ and $\big(\frac i i\big)=1$:

$$p_x = \frac{\hbar}{i} \frac{d}{dx} =(1) \frac{\hbar}{i} \frac{d}{dx}=\bigg(\frac i i\bigg) \frac{\hbar}{i} \frac{d}{dx} = i \frac{\hbar}{(i \cdot i)} \frac{d}{dx} = -i \hbar \frac{d}{dx}$$

Comment: Brilliant, how I didn't think of that was beyond me... cheers!